# Player not colliding with Tilemap 2d collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, my player is not colliding with the tilemap walls that have collision on them... Here is my player movement code

```
 void Update()
    {
        hInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(hInput, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, vInput, 0);
        }
        
        
    }
```

When I move my player they go right through the colliders. They are on the same Layer and both have colliders. Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

**Edit: So I've tested the collisions with OnCollisionEnter2d like suggested and they are colliding, the problem is my player still walks right through the wall. I have no clue why the collider doesn't stop this from happening.**

Comment: First thing I check is layers matrix and if there is a Rigidbody2D on one of the 2 colliding colliders. Or they may be set as triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collider doesn’t actually perform physics like the aftermath of a collision, it just figures out when things are touching. In order to use physics you need a rigidbody or rigidbody2D, which will actually   do something about the collisions the collider detects. Then, instead of setting position you will need to set rb.velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the *Z axis* values are the same.

And just to check if the collisions are actually taking place, do this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    Debug.Log(col.collider.name);
}
```

And make sure that the **Collider** is not a **Trigger**.

These are the only possible problems, and their fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The detection of colliders does not happen in `Update()` method. To detect collision you need to have `OnCollisionEnter()`. This method will be called when another object with collider and rigidbody enter in it. See the official example [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log(collision.collider.name);
}
```